# Get HTTP status code or response headers from <img> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

In this service that I'm building, a request for an image may result in two possible responses.

1. It responds with the requested image.
2. It responds with a default image, and an indication that the requested image is not immediately available.  In this case, the request may be repeated.

The obvious ways to indicate case #2 are either respond with a `202` status code, or an `X-Retry-In` header.  However, I am open to suggestions.

Anyway, my goal is to somehow catch this response in JS (http header/status code/other ideas welcome) and automatically retry the image several seconds later.

I know something approximating this could be done with ajax, but I'd really prefer a solution which uses only JS + <img> tags.

Comment: The only way to get the HTTP headers is to make the HTTP in JS. And that can only be done via an XMLHTTPRequest. *Edit:* Although, you could try to listen to the `error` event on the `img` and see what information it gives you.

Comment: If there's no other way around it, I guess I'll have to resort to HEAD Ajax requests in loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "YOURURL",
dataType: "image/png",
success: function(img) {
  i = new Image();
  i.src = img; // your image
},
error: function(err) {
  i = new Image();
  i.src = 'http://website.site/image.png' // your error image
}
});
```

Comment: This won't work if that image resource at the specified url is not CORS enabled.